# UI Design in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Greetings ,

I am a new developer in BlackBerry Application. I have been working on iphone application too. 
I was really shocked to see the user interface of BlackBerry. Coming from iphone application development it was hard to cope with this new interface.

Now i am working on an application which require a registration page . So far i could only find the normal text field and label field .

I wanted to know if there are any other ways to represent the field like the facebook/ twitter application  in the BlackBerry Applications.

I really appreciate any help available in this regard.

Thanking you,

Alan Varghese Abraham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by saying "field like the facebook/ twitter application" (probably because I'm not a big fan of those). However here is a couple of useful BB UI guides:

1. [UI components](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/UI_components_508102_11.jsp)
2. [How to - Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0)

Yes, I'd say BB is a step behind of iPhone/Android with providing nice/rich UI components out of the box, but the API does allow to create any desired custom `Field`.

Comment: Thank You , The links you have sent were really useful. By fields i meant the textfield where the username and password were set.